# How to set a range for how much letters are being typed in in an input form in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently making password strength checker and I want to check the length of the password and determine the strength of the password. But I do not know how to check the length of the password so that it is like "between 5 and 10 words" or "between 20 to 30 words"

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Password = () => {

    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

    const HandleInputChange = (event) => {
        setPassword(event.target.value)
    }

    const letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
    const capsLetters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
    const numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
    const specialChar = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")"]

    const slicedLetters = letters.slice(...letters)
    const slicedCapsLetters = capsLetters.slice(...capsLetters)
    const slicedNumbers = numbers.slice(...numbers)
    const slicedSpecialChar =   specialChar.slice(...specialChar)

    const [passwordStrength, setPasswordStrength] = useState()

// I am working with this function 
    const StrengthCheck = () => {
        if(password.includes(slicedLetters || capsLetters)) {
            setPasswordStrength("Very Weak")
        } else if(password.includes(slicedLetters && slicedNumbers || slicedCapsLetters)) {
            setPasswordStrength("Weak")
        } else if(password.includes(slicedLetters && slicedNumbers && slicedSpecialChar || slicedCapsLetters)) {
            setPasswordStrength("Medium")
        } else if(password.includes(slicedLetters && slicedCapsLetters && slicedSpecialChar || slicedNumbers)) {
            setPasswordStrength("Strong")
        } else if(password.includes(slicedLetters && slicedCapsLetters && slicedNumbers && slicedSpecialChar)) {
            setPasswordStrength("Very Strong")
        } else {
            setPasswordStrength("Invalid Password to Check!")
        }
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Password Strength Checker</h1>
            <h3>Your Password</h3>
            <input type={"text"} value={password} onChange={HandleInputChange}/>
            <button onClick={StrengthCheck}>Confirm</button>
            <h3>Password display:</h3>
            <input type={"password"} value={password}/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <hr/>
            Your password strength is: <b>{passwordStrength}</b>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Password
```

Comment: The password is a string so it has a property `length` that tells you how many characters it has. Also your checks in the `StrengthCheck` don't work the way you think they do, `password.includes(slicedLetters || capsLetters)` does not check the password against the `slicedLetters` and `capsLetters` but rather selects the first of those two that is truthy and runs `include()` with it only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do that.
Your StrengthCheck function is not perfectly shaped and for considering the length you can create an array something like this,

```
const LengthChecker = [10,20,30,40,50]
```

After this,
You can check this by,

```
var length = text.length;
var _index;
LengthChecker.map((item, index) => {
 if(length < item){
  _index = index;
    break;
}
}
});
console.log(LengthChecker(_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property maxLength={} for having a max length.

For checking the length for measurement purposes you can do value.length or something